# Why is editing Umbraco templates in Visual Studio slow?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, umbraco

I've created an Umbraco 7.1.8 in Visual Studio 2013 using MVC templates. When I edit the templates in Visual Studio the editor slows right down and VS shows a permanent 13% usage in Task Manager. If it helps, I'm using Windows 8.1 64-bit on a machine with a 2.3GHz quad-core cpu. Other projects work fine.

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, found out what the problem was. It turns out if you don't include the .cshtml file in your Visual Studio project (just edit it with Show All Files enabled), you don't get Intellisense and it results in the CPU usage and performance issue I described.

So basically, if you're editing files in Visual Studio, make sure they're included in the project (not greyed out in the Solution Explorer). I'll accept this as the answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: I added all views to the project and that worked for me.